# Twisted: Communicate between deferred sub-process and http requests?

Tags: python, linux, process, twisted

#### Background:

I have a long running sub-process that twisted spawns.
I have subclassed the process protocol in such a way that I'm aware when I receive std out, std err, etc
I would like the ability for separate http requests (over a series of time) to check on the status of these running processes through shared variables or a global class or something.

#### Question:

How do I have the event listener for the sub process protocol "drop off" data for a later http request to "pick up".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a 'mailbox' object; for argument's sake, let's say it's a list.  This could be a dictionary, or an object, or a file, or a database; whatever you want.  Whatever's appropriate to your application.

Then when you instantiate your `ProcessProtocol`, pass a reference to the mailbox.  When relevant data arrives, `self.mailbox.append(relevantData)`.

Also, pass a reference to this object to your HTTP resource that's responding to these requests.  Then, in `render_GET`, `relevantData = self.mailbox.pop()`.

There's no magic way to do this in Twisted.  It all depends on lots of different things about your application and the way you want to store and manage this data, which Twisted is *explicitly* not in charge of.

The question you're really asking here really just boils down to, "I have an object `a` (your process protocol), and an object `b` (your HTTP resource).  How do I get `a` to call a method on `b`?  [This FAQ](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#HowdoImakeinputononeconnectionresultinoutputonanother) shows up in various forms in the Twisted community, over and over again, but it's very hard to write down a nice re-usable answer to it, because everyone thinks they're asking a different question.

What Twisted is doing - *all* Twisted is *ever* doing, really - is mapping the occurrence of events outside of your process - data arriving from subprocesses, the network - into method calls in your process.  How you arrange the objects on the inside, how you keep references between them, and what you do with the data that Twisted has just given you, is *totally up to you*.  This architecture is why Twisted is so powerful.  When you have learned to snatch the error code from the callback, it will be time for you to leave :).

Comment: Glyph, I appreciate the thoughtful answer - thanks for spending the time with your explanation.  One of the technical things I'm trying to wrap my head around is essentially storing variables in the context of the reactor - and then accessing them globally - What I don't understand is what is actually global - doesn't Twisted by default serve from a thread pool? is the render_GET method within the context of the main thread or a sub-thread?

Comment: @Jean-Paul Calderone - Are you sure?  "The default size of the thread pool depends on the reactor being used; the default reactor uses a minimum size of 5 and a maximum size of 10" http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/threading.html

Comment: The reactor has a thread pool for a few special cases.  The thread pool is **not** used for protocols.  HTTP requests are services in the main thread.

Comment: You don't store variables "in the context of the reactor".  You should store variables as attributes of objects.  Maybe you will want to have two servers in the same process one day; why should they have to step on each other just because they share a python interpreter?  If you need an object in your resources, pass it to your resource's constructor when you create it.